# Ubuntu unable to load in Dual Boot after Windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, updates, windows-10, busybox

Using Dual Boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 here.

After a Windows update yesterday the Grub dual boot screen disappeared, which I could fix. Then I got stuck at this screen with this next issue, see also attached screenshot.

I guess the most relevant are the following notices:

*BusyBox v1.30.1 (ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)*

and

*ALERT! UUID=505a2f88-6a67-42db-973e-f2019292557bUUID=505a2f88-6a67-42db-973e-f2019292557b does not exist, Dropping to a shell!*

My system details: Acer Aspire 3 A315-54-52UL

Error details:

[image: Screenshot with error details]

Comment: *the Grub dual boot screen disappeared, which I could fix*... How exactly did you fix it? It should be a matter of opening UEFI settings > Boot and change it back to "Ubuntu", absolutely nothing else. So, please, edit the question and *describe* what you did instead.

Comment: Windows updates may have reset Windows to be default boot. And it may have updated UEFI which reverts to defaults, so check UEFI settings like RAID vs AHCI, Secure Boot off and others. I have multiple settings & have to keep a list. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair